# problems installing GD library on osx 10.6 (snow leopard)

Tags: macos, node.js, gd, gdlib

i want to use the [node-gd](https://github.com/taggon/node-gd) module with node.js and therefore need the GD library installed on my MBP (10.6.8 64bit).

i found this (old) tutorial for osx 10.4
http://www.gisnotes.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/installing_gd2_on_os_x_server.pdf

i followed the walkthrough - except i used the current versions of all libraries:

- [zlib 1.2.5](http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz)
- [jpeg src 8c](http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz)
- [libpng 1.5.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/1.5.4/libpng-1.5.4.tar.gz/download)
- [GD lib 2.0.33](https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd/get/GD_2_0_33.tar.gz)

i can install everything without errors but when i try and startup my node-application which is using the node-gd module, i get the following error:

```
Error: dlopen(/users/phil/node/node_modules/node-gd/build/default/node-gd.node, 1):   Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgd.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/lib/libgd.2.dylib
at Object..node (module.js:432:11)
at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
at require (module.js:364:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/users/phil/node/node_modules/node-gd/node-gd.js:19:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:420:26)
at Object..js (module.js:426:10)
at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
at require (module.js:364:19)
```

so there definitely went something wrong :(

any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck using MacPorts to install libgd. If you do have macports installed try "sudo port install png", "sudo port install jpeg", and "sudo port install gd2". You may then need to copy the gd header and lib files into /usr/include and /usr/lib. After doing this, I was able to get the node-gd test to run with some minor modifications. I was not able to get an npm install of node-gd to run successfully after install however.

Comment: thanks. will try macports then ...

Comment: Which fork of node-gd are you using? Or are you using npm? There seems to be a bit of variation in the way they parse arguments and send them to the gd bindings.

Comment: i used npm to install node-gd (v0.1.7). and i should have mentioned that i installed everything without problems on my older MBP (1.gen 32bit) running 10.6. so i think it has to have sth to do with 32/64bit system.

Comment: @mike finally had the time to try the macports way - but didn't make a difference: same error as before. but macports is installing all packages into /opt/local/ and the error still says sth about /usr/local/ - is it still using the old files? how can i change this?